# MySQL selecting top 4 male scores and top 2 female scores from another table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a MySQL query problem and I have a feeling it will require tables to be joined, but I'm not very experienced in join queries and was wondering if someone could help me at all?

I have two tables. The first one is called 'universities' and looks like this:

```
id | name
 1 | University One
 2 | University Two
```

I also have a second table that looks called competitors that looks like this:

```
id | universityid | male | r1 | r2 | r3 | r4
```

Where 'universityid' is a foreign key referring to the first table, 'male' is a boolean determining the sex of the competitor and r1 - r4 are scores from different rounds of a competition.

So this table might look like:

```
id | universityid | male | r1  | r2  | r3  | r4
-------------------------------------------------
 1 | 1            | 1    | 200 | 100 | 150 | 200
 2 | 1            | 1    | 50  | 100 | 150 | 200
 3 | 1            | 1    | 50  | 100 | 150 | 200
 4 | 1            | 1    | 50  | 100 | 150 | 200
 5 | 1            | 0    | 50  | 100 | 150 | 150
 6 | 1            | 0    | 50  | 100 | 150 | 150
 7 | 2            | 1    | 200 | 200 | 150 | 200
 8 | 2            | 1    | 200 | 100 | 150 | 200
 9 | 2            | 1    | 50  | 100 | 150 | 200
 10| 2            | 1    | 50  | 200 | 150 | 200
 11| 2            | 0    | 50  | 100 | 150 | 150
 12| 2            | 0    | 50  | 100 | 150 | 150
```

What I am trying to do is to find the sum of the top 4 male scores, and the top 2 female scores for each round (r1 - r2) for every university, and return the the total for each round. Then also add them together to make a total score over all rounds for each university, and then order the university rows in DESC order by those totals.

So the return table might look like this

```
university.name | r1total | r2total | r3total | r4total | totalscore
---------------------------------------------------------------------
uni2name        | 600     | 800     | 900     | 1100    | 3400

uni1name        | 450     | 600     | 900     | 1100    | 3050
```

Any help with this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Top 4 male scores for each round?Show some sample data or create a fiddle.

Comment: I have tried editing the OP to make it a little clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT universityid,SUM(r1sum),SUM(r2sum),SUM(r3sum),SUM(r4sum),
SUM(r1sum+r2sum+r3sum+r4sum)as TotalScore 
FROM
(SELECT
 universityid,
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r1 ORDER BY r1 DESC),
   ',', 1)as unsigned)+
 CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r1 ORDER BY r1 DESC),',0'),
   ',', 2),',',-1)as unsigned)+
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r1 ORDER BY r1 DESC),',0'),
   ',', 3),',',-1)as unsigned)+
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r1 ORDER BY r1 DESC),',0'),
   ',', 4),',',-1)as unsigned)as r1sum,
 CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r2 ORDER BY r2 DESC),
   ',', 1)as unsigned)+
 CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r2 ORDER BY r2 DESC),',0'),
   ',', 2),',',-1)as unsigned)+
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r2 ORDER BY r2 DESC),',0'),
   ',', 3),',',-1)as unsigned)+
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r2 ORDER BY r2 DESC),',0'),
   ',', 4),',',-1)as unsigned)as r2sum,
 CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r3 ORDER BY r3 DESC),
   ',', 1)as unsigned)+
 CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r3 ORDER BY r3 DESC),',0'),
   ',', 2),',',-1)as unsigned)+
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r3 ORDER BY r3 DESC),',0'),
   ',', 3),',',-1)as unsigned)+
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r3 ORDER BY r3 DESC),',0'),
   ',', 4),',',-1)as unsigned)as r3sum,
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r4 ORDER BY r4 DESC),
   ',', 1)as unsigned)+
 CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r4 ORDER BY r4 DESC),',0'),
   ',', 2),',',-1)as unsigned)+
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r4 ORDER BY r4 DESC),',0'),
   ',', 3),',',-1)as unsigned)+
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r4 ORDER BY r4 DESC),',0'),
   ',', 4),',',-1)as unsigned)as r4sum


FROM
 competitors
WHERE male=1
GROUP BY
 universityid
UNION ALL
SELECT
 universityid,
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r1 ORDER BY r1 DESC),
   ',', 1)as unsigned)+
 CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r1 ORDER BY r1 DESC),',0'),
   ',', 2),',',-1)as unsigned)as r1sum,
 CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r2 ORDER BY r2 DESC),
   ',', 1)as unsigned)+
 CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r2 ORDER BY r2 DESC),',0'),
   ',', 2),',',-1)as unsigned)as r2sum,
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r3 ORDER BY r3 DESC),
   ',', 1)as unsigned)+
 CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r3 ORDER BY r3 DESC),',0'),
   ',', 2),',',-1)as unsigned)as r3sum,
   CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r4 ORDER BY r4 DESC),
   ',', 1)as unsigned)+
 CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(
   GROUP_CONCAT(r4 ORDER BY r4 DESC),',0'),
   ',', 2),',',-1)as unsigned)as r4sum
FROM
 competitors
WHERE male=0
GROUP BY
 universityid)x
GROUP BY universityid
ORDER BY TotalScore DESC
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db3de/2)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! This is fantastic, apart from if a certain university hasn't entered a full team for a round, then it recounts scores. For instance, if a uni only has 1 male enter in a particular round, it will count his score 4 times over, when it should just count it once and leave the other scores as 0. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I made one other mistake in the OP which I have corrected now. It was suppose to return the name of the University and not the uni's id.

Comment: I tried it on mine, and the top row returns all 0s appart from the uni name. The second row displays results... but then it also only displays too rows when my test data has three unis in it?? Thanks for your help with the matter by the way!

Comment: this is what i get http://postimg.org/image/6l9tz0x21/ ... maybe its to do with test data having zeros in it...?

Comment: @JamesMcIlveen Also add images with your tables data

Comment: @JamesMcIlveen Thats really weird,I`ll think about it.

Comment: @JamesMcIlveen Apparently you have to have a male and female row for each university to appear in the results,but I cant figure out why.But i`ll try to figure it out.Try adding some rows to your data to see if this is true for you also.

Comment: @JamesMcIlveen Changed it,hope it`s still useful.